# db.get() vs db.get_by_key_name() performance (GAE BIgtable/Datastore)

Tags: google-app-engine, scalability, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

How does the performance of db.get() compare with that of db.get_by_key_name()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[get_by_key_name](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name) must compute the keys based on app, model, name and parent, so it should consume a (tiny but not null) amount of CPU more than `db.get`, which needs no computation. However I doubt you can measure the difference in elapsed time, since the fetching from storage will vastly dominate in both cases.

Answer (score 4):

For all intents and purposes they are equivalent.